# Problem with Select and Pick

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to filter a data file choosing those elements that match a condition and then plot them. Here is the corresponding code I use:

```
data = Import["data.out", "Table"];
pick[m_List, i_Integer] := Module[{s = m[[i, 8]]}, Pick[m, s, s != 0]];
dataP = Table[{PointSize[0.005], Red, pick[data, i], 
  Point[{data[[i, 3]], data[[i, 4]], data[[i, 5]]}]}, {i, 1, Length[data]}]
```

The module `pick` is supposed to choose those elements from the list `m` for which $s\neq 0$. However, it does not work and therefore all the elements of the list are plotted. I used also `Select[m, s !=0]` but with no success. What am I doing wrong?

This is a small sample of the data file

```
data1={{-4.05, -0.48, -1.4648, -1.36804, -1.7282, 648.01, 1.03023*10^-13, 7},
{-4.05, -0.41, -1.2762, 1.7369, 1.55982, 278.54, 1.99574*10^-14, 0},
{-4.05, -0.34, -1.54191, 1.42069, 1.59888, 178.32, 9.0609*10^-14, 5}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always try to provide a sample data. Since I don't know what you're trying to get with `m[[i, 8]]`. Note that both `m` and `s` must have the same `Length` for `Pick` to work.

You're using `Pick` wrong. `Pick` expects a pattern for it's third argument and you haven't provided one. Do this instead:

```
   filered = Pick[data1, data1[[All, 8]], x_ /; x != 0]  

  (* {{-4.05, -0.48, -1.4648, -1.36804, -1.7282, 648.01, 1.03023*10^-13, 7}, 
{-4.05, -0.34, -1.54191, 1.42069, 1.59888, 178.32,   9.0609*10^-14, 5}} *)
```

OR you can use `Select` as follows:

```
Select[data1, #[[8]] != 0 &]
```

OR

```
DeleteCases[data1, {x__, 0}]
```

Now you can proceed to plot the filtered data.

```
plotpoints = filtered[[All, {3, 4, 5}]]
```

> {{-1.4648, -1.36804, -1.7282}, {-1.54191, 1.42069, 1.59888}}

Now using one of the `3D` plot options that accepts data points should be all you need.

Comment: I posted a small sample of the data file. I want to choose all the items that have nonzero last element.

Comment: `s = m[[i,8]]` is the element of the last (eight) column.

Comment: The target is to read the external file, exclude all lines with zero eighth column and then create a 3D plot of the third, fourth and fifth elements of that lines.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z. See my edit. Does this do what you want?

Comment: Yes it does. But the question remains unsolved. Now, we just bypassed the problem. How can `Select` work right inside my original module?

Comment: `i` is a simple counter starting from 1 all the way to the end of the length of the list in order to test all the items.

Answer (score 1):

Just to illustrate some options:

```
op1 = Cases[data1, Except[{__, 0}]];
op2 = Select[data1, #[[8]] != 0 &];
op3 = Pick[data1, (#[[8]] != 0 & /@ data1), True];
op1 == op2 == op3;
{Red, Point[#]} & /@ op1[[;; , {3, 4, 5}]]
```

Note the equlaity test is true. I hope I am interpreting correctly that R^3 point is aimed to be plotted.