# How to cut elements from set of data based on function restrictions?

Tags: list-manipulation

For example, say I have a set of data which takes the form

```
list = {{1,2,4,5,3,2},{2,3,4,2,1,6},{2,3,4,5,4,3}}
```

where all of the elements have a length of 6. Then I have to run this `list` through many functions each with various restrictions e.g.:

```
ptOf[event_]:=px+py/;(px+py)<4,
```

where `px` is the first element in the 6 vector `{px,py,_,_,_,_}` and `py` is the second element.

How would I cut the elements from the original list that do not satisfy this condition?

Comment: I don't really get it but `Select[list, #[[1]] + #[[2]] < 4 &]`?

Comment: Thank you.  Just what I was looking for.

Comment: This is an extremely common class of question.  In addition to the **Linked** questions under the original see also e.g. [(11219)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11219),
[(11780)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11780),
[(30155)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30155),
[(33880)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33880).  For clarity I would use: `Cases[list, {a_, b_, ___} /; a + b < 4]`.  For speed choose numeric methods using e.g. `UnitStep`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this special case you need to use `Select` and `Part` a.k.a. `[[]]`:

```
list = {{1,2,4,5,3,2},{2,3,4,2,1,6},{2,3,4,5,4,3}}  
Select[list, #[[1]] + #[[2]] < 4 &]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 2}}
> ```